# How to I overlay text inside the header that contains a full width image

Tags: html, css

Using the two files included, when I use the class mainImage, I get no image in the header of the webpage, but when I use just the header in the CSS I get the image on my page.  Can someone explain why?

Also, how can I get text inside of the header (layer over the image) when I successfully get the image in the header?  At present, the text is above the header image.

```css
* {
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  color: #222222;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/*  When I use .mainImage and comment out header from line 16, I receive no image in the header of the web page.
    .mainImage {
     background-image: url('/images/snowy-mountain-wide.jpg');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
     max-width: 100%;
     padding-bottom: 9%;
    }
    */

header {
  background-image: url('/images/snowy-mountain-wide.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 9%;
}

p {
  font-family: cursive, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-indent: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <!--#include file="header.html"-->
  <header class="mainImage" alt="Mountain">
    <div class="header">

      This is a test that should be in the head.

    </div>
  </header>

  <div id="body">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "line 16" is what line?

Comment: can you check the location of the image and see if it matches what's in your css?

Comment: By the way, this <div class="header"> does nothing because your CSS is using a tag selector ( header ) and not a class selector ( .header )

Comment: Just a random comments, your header rule in your css is written for the header tag and not as a class. Your image should show up in the background of the container as a backdrop for the contents of the container, (i.e., the text).

Comment: Does this help you? https://jsfiddle.net/t5zp6du1/

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments and help.  There is so much to learn.

Davvy, your example helped a lot and the clean code was great.
Nocturns2 & Jonathan Chaplin: thanks for the comments.  That helps explain things too.

Comment: I also see the wiki image is at 3264 x 1832, my image is 1024 x 210 and when I add my image, it doesn't expand the full width of the page.  How can I get it to the full width without adding to the height?  Thanks

Comment: I got it, I added background-size: cover; back to the header.
Again thank you everyone.